# How can I test if pixels are being sent to my arduino?

Tags: arduino-mega

If I'm using `digitalWrite();` to send a clock impulse to a camera and then get analog signal back, how can I check to see if these pixels are in fact returning? Since there is no console how can I see if any values are actually being returned?

I'm using an Arduino Mega with the TSL1401 Linear Array Scanner.

Comment: There is a console - it's called `Serial`.

Comment: Send clocks, read the ADC in between, print out the results.  Change the light pattern on the sensor.  Consider the phase relationship between the clock and the ADC conversion time.  Consider using an oscilloscope, or even find a sketch that makes the Arduino into a crude scope with data plotted using processing or something like that on the PC end, and modify that to add clocks to the sensor in between the readings.

Comment: @Majenko Where is it in the IDE? Isn't `Serial` a pin on the Arduino?

Comment: @FortunaIwasaki It's the little icon in the top right of a magnifying glass with dots behind it. "Serial Monitor" or something it's called. Any `Serial.println()` etc you execute will come out there.